# cannot resolve symbol on calling an android class outside of MainActivity

Tags: java, android, class, object

I want to split my downloadTask class and I created a new class file, but when I try to call that class in MainAcvtivity, I get Cannot resolve downloadTask();

```
public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask <String ,Void,String>{

public String desURL;
public String Date;
Context context;
private downloadTask(String desURL, String Date,Context context){

    this.desURL = desURL;
    this.Date = Date;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    //this method will be running on UI thread

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args){

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    //this method will be running on UI thread

}

}
```

please help to resolve the problem and use my downloadTask class in MainActivity.

here is my MainActivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context = this;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.last_update_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lastUpdate = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.last_update_key),"0");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    if(lastUpdate == "0"){

        Toast.makeText(this,R.string.need_for_update,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

Comment: add your main activity code or try new downloadTask().exucute();

Comment: @Pavya Didn't solve the problem!

Comment: i can't see any `downloadTask` class related code in mainacitivity plus , `context` is null

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh is right make it public then new downloadTask(desUrl, date, context ).exucute()

Answer (score 1):

You have a `private` constructor so the objects of this class cannot be created from other classes so make it `public`

```
/*private*/ public downloadTask(String desURL, String Date,Context context){

    this.desURL = desURL;
    this.Date = Date;
    this.context = context;

}
```

Tip: move below code inside `onCreate` because `context` will be null

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.last_update_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
lastUpdate = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.last_update_key),"0");
```

Comment: then can you show how you are using it ,because `private` clearly was an issue which won't let you create object of this class

Answer (score 0):

I made downloadTask file in java(Test) section by mistake and after moving it, my problem solved

Comment: and do you think it's working with `private downloadTask`? plus you got a clear exception here `context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.last_update_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`